# Tag a page revision on mediawiki and access revisions by tags

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I develop an application which has a manual/help system on a mediawiki site. When the user needs help in the application, he/she can click a button and access the corresponding help page on the wiki. This works pretty well and it is easy to keep the manual updated when I add/change functionality in the application.

Now I will release a new version of the application but some users will still use the old version. I would like to be able to "tag" an old revision of a page, e.g "#version1.0" and tag the new revision "#version2.0" and then when I link from the old application I link with the tag "#version1.0".

The reason why I want to have two versions of some pages is that some functionality changes between version1 and version2 and I want the users to be able to get the correct help/guides regardless of which version the users use.

I know that I can make a copy of the current wiki and call that version1 and then use the current installation for version2 but I want to avoid having two wikis on the same server.

So, is there a solution for this problem? I have tried to search for built-in solutions and extensions but could not find anything good..

Comment: [FlaggedRevs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FlaggedRevs) can do that, although it is a b it complicated to set up.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking of a wiki with few pages, you can simply hardcode a **permalink** to the specific revision appropriate for the release in question. The permalink is a link which contains the parameter **oldid=**; in most skins it's found in the "tools" section of the sidebar.

If there are more pages but your users are minimally competent, you can either

- hardcode *all* links to the current revision of all pages and trust that they'll follow the banner at the top to see more recent versions where needed ([example](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Help:History&oldid=890165)), or
- link the page history instead, with the appropriate year/month/offset/limit parameter ([example](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Help%3AHistory&action=history&year=2014&month=1&limit=1)), and trust that the user will click the suggested version or switch to more recent versions if really needed.

Otherwise, the "standard" MediaWiki way is sadly to run parallel pages for the different but similar content. There is another question for that scenario, IIRC focused on Wikibooks books for different versions of a same software.